# Android, getting an exception that is crashing my app

Tags: android, exception

I am a noob learning android by making a simple game:
There are a few buttons that the user can press
I show some questions on the screen and he has to press one of the buttons as the answer
when he presses the button I play a sound.
3 wrong answers and the game is over.

Simple right?
Everything works and I have learned a lot except for one "#%#"%"# exception that keeps crashing my app :(

It's really strange, on 3 wrong answers the game is over so I run this code:

```
soundPool.release();            
this.finish();
```

which sends the user back to the last activity and they can start the game again.
The problem arises every 3-5 times that they restart the game... I get a force close and this in logcat:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/90/91939698.png/

The error seems to be here:

```
public void playSound(int sound) {

AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)GameScreen.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float streamVolumeMax = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);    
float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;

/** The below line is line 117 that is crashing the program */
soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);     
}
```

Please advise on how I can crush this annoying "bug".

Thanks!
Ryan

***================================================================================***

**EDIT:**

in onCreate I am doing this:

```
new LoadMusicInBackground().execute();
```

and LoadMusicInBackground is this:

```
/** Helper class to load all the music in the background. */
class LoadMusicInBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> 
{ 
    @Override 
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) { 

        soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

            soundPoolMap.put(A1,    soundPool.load(GameScreen.this, R.raw.a,    1));                
            soundPoolMap.put(A3,    soundPool.load(GameScreen.this, R.raw.b,    1));         
            soundPoolMap.put(A5,    soundPool.load(GameScreen.this, R.raw.c_s,  1));
            soundPoolMap.put(A6,    soundPool.load(GameScreen.this, R.raw.d,    1));       
            soundPoolMap.put(A8,    soundPool.load(GameScreen.this, R.raw.e,    1)); 
            soundPoolMap.put(A10,   soundPool.load(GameScreen.this, R.raw.f_s,  1)); 
            soundPoolMap.put(A12,   soundPool.load(GameScreen.this, R.raw.g_s,  1));
            soundPoolMap.put(wrong, soundPool.load(GameScreen.this, R.raw.wrong2,   1));

            publishProgress(""); 
        Log.v("SOUNDPOOL",""+soundPoolMap);
      return(null); 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) 
    { 
        //text1.setText(item[0]);
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) { 
      //Toast .makeText(GameScreen.this, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

...

**EDIT:**

> public final void **release()**
>   Release the SoundPool resources. Release all memory and native
>   resources used by the SoundPool object. The SoundPool can no longer be
>   used and the reference should be set to null.

You cannot reuse soundPool object once you call release, so you need to create a new instance. So do this to make sure it is not resued:

```
   soundPool.release();
   soundPool = null;
```

Comment: Doing that it just goes on as normal while giving me a null pointer exception (but not crashing). Edited the OP to add more code, according to the log statement there, the background thread is not starting the 4-5th time so soundpool becomes null. :(

Comment: Nope, on the 5th time again the background thread fails to start :(

Comment: I am starting 3 threads like this: new LoadMusicInBackground().execute();
  new GameRunningNotesTimer().execute(); new LoadMusicInBackground().execute(); for some reason on every 5th time the background one fails :(( Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try logging soundPool and soundPoolMap as it looks like one of these are null.
Perhaps as part of restarting the game these values are cleared?

Comment: Thats what I don't understand, if thats the case why does it work 4-5 times everytime before this happens?

Comment: It could be something weird like a race condition. Do you ever explicity set soundPool or soundPoolMap to null?

Comment: Ok, edited the above to add more code, according to the log statement there, the background thread is not starting the 4-5th time so soundpool becomes null.

Answer (score 0):

For a *noob* you're doing quite well :-D

I think this is causing your problem:

```
soundPool.release();
```

You're probably releasing it and try to reuse it next time. See [release()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#release%28%29) documentation....

Comment: Thanks! :) Taking out the release is also giving me the same error :(

Comment: I can upload my code if you want, its not a big secret or anything, just a newbie project :)